# Como usar "ajax" con el "scaffold" de Ruby on Rails

Tags: javascript, ajax, ruby-on-rails, reactjs, post

Buenas, estoy usando (REACT Y Ruby on Rails) juntos y `ajax` y `scaffold` juntos para hacer un `POST`, `PUT`, `DESTROY`, `GET` pero al momento de hacer el `POST` simplemente no hace nada, este es mi codigo:

```
handleClick() {
        var name    = this.refs.name.value;
        var description = this.refs.description.value;
        $.ajax({
            url: '/items',
            type: 'POST',
            data: { item: { name: name, description: description } },
            success: (item) => {
                this.props.handleSubmit(item);
            }
        });
    }
```

Boton:

```
<button onClick={this.handleClick}>Submit</button>
```

Controlador:

```
class ItemsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_item, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /items
  # GET /items.json
  def index
    @items = Item.all
  end

  # GET /items/1
  # GET /items/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /items/new
  def new
    @item = Item.new
  end

  # GET /items/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /items
  # POST /items.json
  def create
    @item = Item.new(item_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @item.save
        format.html { redirect_to @item, notice: 'Item was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @item }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @item.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /items/1
  # PATCH/PUT /items/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @item.update(item_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @item, notice: 'Item was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @item }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @item.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /items/1
  # DELETE /items/1.json
  def destroy
    @item.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to items_url, notice: 'Item was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_item
      @item = Item.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def item_params
      params.require(:item).permit(:name, :description)
    end
end
```

El detalle es que al momento de presionar el `submit` solo recarga la pagina y no agrega nada. en consola no muestra ningún error, y como soy nuevo con ajax. por eso solicito me puedan ayudar.

Answer (score 0):

Esto se debe a que tu controlador no sabe como responder a la petición; necesitas agregar una respuesta en tu controlador para formato `js`, por ejemplo:

```
def destroy
  @item.destroy
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to items_url, notice: 'Item was successfully destroyed.' }
    format.json { head :no_content }
    format.js { }
  end
end
```

Con este ajuste tu controlador podrá responder en el formato que `ajax` le pide (i.e. `js`).

De igual forma debes adecuar tu acción `update` para que responda a `js`.

Answer (score 0):

Al parecer estás haciendo un submit común y corriente. Prueba con:

```
handleClick(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  // El resto de tu código
}
```

Answer (score 0):

buen dia, primero debes definir una ruta en el archivos de routes.rb
post 'definicion', to 'controlador#nombredelafuncion'
en mi caso la definicion se llama insertar_equipo el controlador inventories y la funcion: InsercionConNombrenoConvencional(estoy porbando si puedo insertar con algo diferete de create)

queda asi:
post 'insertar_equipo',to:'inventories#InsercionConNombrenoConvencional'

en mi ajax hago lo siguiente:(obviamente llamado desde un onclick y teniendo jquery instalado en el proyecto anteriormente)

$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: 'insertar_equipo',
data:{'authenticity_token':$('input[name="authenticity_token"]').val(),
'nombre':$("#nombre").val(),
'descripcion':$("#descripcion").val(),
'precio':$("#precio").val(),
'cantidad':$("#cantidad").val()
},
success: function(res) {
console.log(res)
}
});

notar que estoy enviando el authenticity_token es porque en rails estoy trabajando con un formulario generado por =form_with(model:@variable) to |form|

y en el controlador inventories
def InsercionConNombrenoConvencional
@articulo = Inventory.new(nombre: params[:nombre],descripcion: params[:descripcion],precio: params[:precio],cantidad: params[:cantidad])
@articulo.save

esto guarda en la base de datos (PERO NO SE COMO ENVIAR UNA RESPUESTA AUXILIO)

Comment: No olvides agregar formato al código. ¿Qué quisiste decir en tu última oración? (lo que está en mayúsculas sostenidas)